# Is it possible to deploy rails3 and rails4 in the same server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I just want to know if is possible to deploy to passenger a project that I have in rails3 (ruby-1.9.3) and another project in rails4 (ruby-2.0.0). I have installed ruby using RVM on my production server, I'm just wondering if is going to be possible to have 2 different projects on the same production server.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem in that, but there're couple things that you need to do first.

1. Install `nginx` instead of `Apache` and use it with `unicorn`.  You can find a whole lot of setup guides depending on your production server OS, or use the `capistrano-nginx-unicorn` gem if you use Capistrano for deployment.
2. Use the `rvm-capistrano` gem to manage the ruby versions and gemsets used in each project. It's pretty well documented, but if you have further questions, feel free to ask.

If you'll need any further help, you may also consider asking on the freenode#rvm channel. I found some great hints there.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, right now I have an Apache and deploying with capistrano, but I will try nginx with unicorn

Comment: @Crysfel nginx is faster and more stable then Apache.